# Trim data using lapply to remove outliers

Tags: r, lapply, desctools

I am trying to use `lapply` to trim some of my data. What I am trying to do is trim columns `2:4` (deleting the outliers or extreme values) but also remove the rows across the columns.

Some data with outliers in each column. So I want to remove values `100` and `-100` in `V1` but also remove the whole row in the data. Also removing values `80` and `-80` in column `V2` - subsequently removing that row also.

```
    trimdata <- NULL
    trimdata$ID <-  seq.int(102)
    trimdata$V1 <- c(rnorm(100), 100, -100)
    trimdata$V2 <- c(rnorm(100), 80, -80)
    trimdata$V3 <- c(rnorm(100), 120, -120)
    trimdata <- as.data.frame(trimdata)

    library(DescTools)
    trimdata <- lapply(trimdata, function(x) Trim(x, trim = 0.01))
    trimdata <- as.data.frame(trimdata)
```

The above code applies the function across all the columns (removing the extreme values in the ID column)

This code:

```
trimdata[2:4] <- lapply(trimdata[2:4], function(x) Trim(x, trim = 0.01))
```

Returns the following error

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 2:4, value = list(V1 = c(0.424725933773568,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 98 rows, need 100
```

So I am trying to trim based on columns 2:4 but also apply it to column 1.

Comment: What is `Trim`??

Comment: It takes the extreme 1% of the data and removes it. In my untouched data I had a mean for one column of 14.5, trimming the top 1% brought it down to 11, trimming the top 10% brought it down to just 10. So I am using it as a way to remove the extreme values.

Comment: So, where did you get it from? Any packages? Or is it a custom function?

Comment: Apologies, I think I got it from the `DescTools` package.

Comment: Can you make sure and add it in your question please?

Comment: I have been looking and I am using the `DescTools` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace values in the `trimdata` because function `Trim` removes elements and you lose the length equality necessary to the substitution.

Here an example:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
length(x)
[1] 10
length(Trim(x, trim=0.1))
[1] 8
```

Before `Trim` function you have 10 elements, after only 8.

In your example `Trim` removes 2 elements, so you have this description in the error:

> replacement element 1 has 98 rows, need 100

From `Trim` documentation:

> A symmetrically trimmed vector x with a fraction of trim observations
>   (resp. the given number) deleted from each end will be returned.

In your example two rows by each column are trimmed out. Rows are differents for each column as you can see:

```
trim_out<-lapply(trimdata[2:4], function(x) Trim(x, trim = 0.01))
lapply(trim_out, attributes)
$V1
$V1$trim
[1] 56 57


$V2
$V2$trim
[1] 63 47


$V3
$V3$trim
[1] 90 74
```

If you want a cleaned data.frame in output you can remove all this rows from your dataframe `trimdata`, like this:

```
trimdata[-unique(unlist(lapply(trim_out, attributes))),]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Those 2 elements that have been removed, I am trying to remove from the `ID` column also. So once the `Trim` function finds an extreme value, remove it from the whole data frame. If I save the output into a different data.frame I will have data of two different lengths, which would be okay if I could some how `cbind(x, y, by = 'ID`) but that is not possible.